# Can I get a software that records PC History?

Tags: windows, logs, history

I want a software that records PC history (which apps were opened and when exactly? Which settings have been changed and when if possible?) in layman terms. I have tried using Event Viewer but I have not been able to fully comprehend it.

Any suggestions would be welcome as well as suggestions on how to appropriately use Event Viewer would also be appreciated.

Comment: This will be hard to do, because of the "layman terms". For such a feature, someone would need to define which actions are relevant and which are not. Probably, **you** are the only one who can. And if you don't, you're likely overwhelmed by the amount of information that is given to you. At every startup, the PC starts maybe 100 programs, all of which are possibly not relevant to you. The question therefore is: what purpose should the app have, except just recording everything. What problem are you trying to solve for which you think such an app would be helpful?

Comment: The question is why do you need to?  Perhaps there is a different solution

Comment: You could always do a screen capture of . . . everything.

Comment: The problem is you don't realize how much windows is doing behind the curtain.  Process Monitor by sysinternals will record these transactions, but you will have 100,000 transactions in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

On GNU/Linux, no additional software is necessary. See this guide: https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/linux-logging-basics/

Comment: It seems OP is using Windows, because he has Event Viewer

Answer (score 0):

As @Kresimir said in Linux there is Linux System Logs.

But in Windows there is the Windows Event Viewer which is the same.

Both are a bit impractical to use as you have to dive into tons of logs. If using the Windows Event Viewer filter is too hard I suggest you to find online a tool that could help you target what you are looking for:

- https://www.raymond.cc/blog/a-built-in-system-monitor-thats-easier-to-read-than-event-viewer/
- https://windowsreport.com/best-windows-10-event-log-viewers/